# Can I command npm not to attempt any downloads from the internet?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have copied npm caches onto a machine that has no internet access. When installing, it attempts to go online before falling back to the local cached versions and this seems to be slowing things down a lot:

> npm install gulp -g --verbose
> npm info it worked if it ends with ok
> npm verb cli [
> npm verb cli   'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe',
> npm verb cli   'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js',
> npm verb cli   'install',
> npm verb cli   'gulp',
> npm verb cli   '-g',
> npm verb cli   '--verbose'
> npm verb cli ]
> npm info using npm@6.14.15
> npm info using node@v14.17.6
> npm verb npm-session 85d023355611a2b7
> npm WARN registry Unexpected warning for https://registry.npmjs.org/: Miscellaneous Warning ECONNREFUSED: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/gulp failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 104.16.18.35:443
> npm WARN registry Using stale data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.
> npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/gulp 73192ms (from cache)
> npm timing stage:loadCurrentTree Completed in 73766ms
> npm timing stage:loadIdealTree:cloneCurrentTree Completed in 3ms
> npm timing stage:loadIdealTree:loadShrinkwrap Completed in 120ms
> npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/vinyl-fs 73164ms (from cache)
> npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/gulp-cli 73177ms (from cache)
> npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/glob-watcher 73180ms (from cache)
> npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/undertaker 73180ms (from cache)
> npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/anymatch 73116ms (from cache)
> npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/chokidar 73118ms (from cache)
> npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/async-done 73122ms (from cache)
> npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/normalize-path 73121ms (from cache)
> npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/just-debounce 73122ms (from cache)
> npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/is-negated-glob 73124ms (from cache)
> npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/object.defaults 73126ms (from cache)

All these 73s failures are taking forever.

Can I tell it "use the offline cache only" somehow? I'm running mpm 6.14.15 against node 14.17.6 due to some compatibility issues,

Comment: Have you tried to pass the `offline` flag ? https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/config#offline

Comment: @Peterrabbit I never saw this - I think that might be the simple answer I need!  If you write it up as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the npm `--offline` flag

Docs https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/config#offline